# Can I use the Blade templating engine outside of Laravel?

Tags: php, design-patterns, frameworks, laravel-blade

i'm want to creating a design pattern and use the "Blade templating engine".
Can I use the Blade templating engine outside of Laravel and use it in my new pattern ?

Comment: It is an alternative: https://corviz.github.io/crow/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the record:

I tested many libraries to run blade outside Laravel (that i don't use) and most are poor hacks of the original library that simply copied and pasted the code and removed some dependencies yet it retains a lot of dependencies of Laravel.

So I created (for a project) an alternative for blade that its free (MIT license, i.e. close source/private code is OK) in a **single file and without a single dependency of an external library**.  You could download the class and start using it, or you could install via composer.

https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne

https://packagist.org/packages/eftec/bladeone

It's 100% compatible without the Laravel's own features (extensions).

How it works:

```
<?php
include "lib/BladeOne/BladeOne.php";
use eftec\bladeone;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views'; // folder where is located the templates
$compiledFolder = __DIR__ . '/compiled';
$blade=new bladeone\BladeOne($views,$compiledFolder);
echo $blade->run("Test.hello", ["name" => "hola mundo"]);
?>
```

Another alternative is to use twig but I tested it and I don't like it. I like the syntax of Laravel that its close to ASP.NET MVC Razor.

**Edit: To this date (July 2018), it's practically the only template system that supports the new features of Blade 5.6 without Laravel. ;-)**

Comment: This library is fantastic, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Matt Stauffer has created a whole repository showing you how you can use various Illuminate components directly outside of Laravel. I would recommend following his example and looking at his source code.

https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch

Here is the index.php of using Laravel Views outside of Laravel

https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/blob/master/components/view/index.php

You can write a custom wrapper around it so that you can call it like Laravel

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
use Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine;
use Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineResolver;
use Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine;
use Illuminate\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;

function view($viewName, $templateData)
{
    // Configuration
    // Note that you can set several directories where your templates are located
    $pathsToTemplates = [__DIR__ . '/templates'];
    $pathToCompiledTemplates = __DIR__ . '/compiled';

    // Dependencies
    $filesystem = new Filesystem;
    $eventDispatcher = new Dispatcher(new Container);

    // Create View Factory capable of rendering PHP and Blade templates
    $viewResolver = new EngineResolver;
    $bladeCompiler = new BladeCompiler($filesystem, $pathToCompiledTemplates);

    $viewResolver->register('blade', function () use ($bladeCompiler) {
        return new CompilerEngine($bladeCompiler);
    });

    $viewResolver->register('php', function () {
        return new PhpEngine;
    });

    $viewFinder = new FileViewFinder($filesystem, $pathsToTemplates);
    $viewFactory = new Factory($viewResolver, $viewFinder, $eventDispatcher);

    // Render template
    return $viewFactory->make($viewName, $templateData)->render();
}
```

You can then call this using the following

```
view('view.name', ['title' => 'Title', 'text' => 'This is text']);
```

Comment: Still works in 2024! Latest update to Torch was for Laravel 8.x, but it might work on later versions, too.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, there are lots of standalone blade options on packagist, as long as you are comfortable with composer then there should be no issue, [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/jenssegers/blade) looks pretty interesting due to having a really high percentage of stars compared to downloads.

Be warned though i have not tried it myself, like you i was looking for a standalone option for my own project and came across it, i will be giving it a real good workout though at sometime in the near future,

Comment: I also use another package of his : date. He's a reliable developer imho.

Comment: @MartinJJ Any update as to how well it worked for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it where ever you like. Just install one of the the many packages available on composer for it.

If you're interested in integrating it with codeigniter I have a [blog post here outlining the process](https://web.archive.org/web/20170525222604/http://mstd.eu/index.php/2017/03/02/using-the-laravel-blade-templating-engine-in-codeigniter-3/).

Following the above steps should make it obvious how to include it into any framework.