# How to replace <?php echo with curly brace({{ }})

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-blade

I want to cleanup my php file. I really like the way how blade template use curly brace to display php variables `{{ $user }}` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data

Is there a way to use a functionality like that without using blade template. Using `<?php echo $user ?>` get's very repetitive.

Comment: no, if you want a templating engine, use one, you can enable [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) and shorten it to `<?= stuff ?>` if you want.

Comment: Why don't you want to use blade? It provides the exact functionality you're wanting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the Blade templating engine outside of Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273762/can-i-use-the-blade-templating-engine-outside-of-laravel)

Comment: There are many templating engine. I'm not quite sure how Laravel work, but I can't think of any reason why they would prevent you for using another one than Blade. You can look at Twig too ! If you feel like doing one of your own you can also read their code because I'm surei t must be very instructive !

Comment: You can either use blade template or can use sort tag like <?= $user; ?>

Comment: @Zyigh Is right. There are many template engines to choose from, and Laravel makes it easy to swap in whichever you choose. But without knowing why you don't like blade it's hard to recommend any because a lot of them are very similar.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in PHP without using a template engine because it is a different syntax. Anyway in my opinion sometimes it is not the best idea to use a template engine ***because PHP is already kind of a template engine***.

All what you seem to care about is the *short syntax* of echoing a variable in blade:

```
{{ user }}
```

This is as short as the syntax *the PHP template engine itself* provides:

```
<?= $user ?>
```

Of course Laravel (and similar) has a good reason to use template engine like blade - in order to seperate controller, logic and view (such that the view can be made by non-programmer designers for instance).

***Update (thx to comments):*** The codes provided above *do not exactly do the same* as template engines (as an additional layer) may take care of e.g. escaping variables, which adds safety to the code.

As the OPs' code has already been built with echo and he is just searching for a replacement I did not mention this, but its a notable difference that you have to take care of some things yourself if not using one.

Comment: I have to downvote this because of the "it is not the best idea to use a template engine". `<?=` is **not** the same here. Laravel's `{{ }}` applies automatic escaping, which largely prevents accidental XSS vulnerabilities in Blade. Just one small example of why a templating engine can have significant benefits.

Comment: @ceejayoz So what? If you need automatic escaping put an escaping function around the variable (or maybe you have escaped it in your earlier code?). You do not need it in many cases though.

Just because laravel adds some sugar to echo it does not make this a bad answer.

Comment: "This is exactly as short as the syntax the PHP template engine itself provides" Is not accurate. As @ceejayoz points out blade applies character escaping automatically. Providing information that is factually inaccurate is what makes it a bad answer.

Comment: I've been coding PHP for about two decades now. Sure, you *can* put an escaping function around it. People often **don't** - I've seen so many XSS vulnerabilities due to insecure coding practices. As a result, I think Laravel's "always escaped unless you specifically turn it off" approach built into the framework's best practices is of significant benefit.

Comment: @jfadich Thx for the notice. Updated in order to avoid potential misunderstandings.